# mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(i) crashes on Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to update a single TextView in my RecyclerView. I tried using mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(1); but this crashes the app and I can't figure out why. Calling mNumbersList.setAdapter(mAdapter); works fine.

Here is my adapter:

```
public class GreenAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GreenAdapter.NumberViewHolder> {

private final String TAG = GreenAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private int mNumberItems;


public GreenAdapter(int numberOfItems) {
    mNumberItems = numberOfItems;
}

@Override
public NumberViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
    int layoutIdForListItem;
    if (viewType==1) { layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.first; } else {  layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.number_list_item; }
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;

    View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, viewGroup, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
    NumberViewHolder viewHolder = new NumberViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    int First;
    switch (position) {
        case 0: First=1;
            break;
        default:
            First = 0;
    }
    return First;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NumberViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.d(TAG, "#" + position);
    holder.bind(position);
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mNumberItems;
}

class NumberViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    TextView listItemNumberView;


    public NumberViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        listItemNumberView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV1);
    }


    void bind(int listIndex) {
        //String[] messages = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.messageArray);
         //listItemNumberView.setText(messages[listIndex]);
        switch (listIndex) {
            case 0: if (setStatusError) {Status="Cannot connect to eve-central";} listItemNumberView.setText(Status);
                break;
            case 1: listItemNumberView.setText(Buy[listIndex-1]+"    "+Sell[listIndex-1]);
                break;
            case 2: listItemNumberView.setText(Buy[listIndex-1]+"    "+Sell[listIndex-1]);
                break;
            default:listItemNumberView.setText(String.valueOf(listIndex));
        }
    }
}
}
```

EDIT: Nevermind I am stupid. I had a handler that does this but it already starts before the RecyclerView is called...

Comment: Post your error log!

Comment: @Wizard thanks, I already found the problem.